# Surface area of revolution; $y=0.25x^3$, $0\le x\le 2$, revolved around $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I'm trying to solve the surface area of revolution for the function $y=0.25x^3$ revolved around $x$-axis from $0\le x\le 2$.

I got the answer $14.253$ using $$2\pi \int_0^2  0.25x^3 \sqrt{1+(0.75x^2)^2}\,dx$$

And according to my college prof I'm wrong.

Can someone help me find my mistake?

Comment: I reformatted the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). As a member for over a year, with 14 questions posted, you should have had plenty of opportunities to learn the markup.

Comment: Your answer looks right to me.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the integral you've used, and Wolfram Alpha confirms your answer.

Comment: Maybe check that you understood the problem itself correctly. If there are no mistakes with that, ask the professor to clarify what's wrong.

Comment: I am 100% sure that's how the problem was worded. I have it infront of me

Comment: I'll ask tomorrow if there was a typo on the sheet maybe? I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick shot at it. <strike>Leave out the square root and integrate.</strike>

a = π/2 * x^4 / 4  | from 0 to 2

= 16 π / 8

= 2π

Do it the way you started. This is why I like coming here. I find out what I let get rusty. No areas of revolution integrals for almost 40 years....

Ok, let's try this:

a = 2π∫ 0->2 (1/4)*x^3/4 * (1 + 9/16 x^4)^(1/2) dx

Let's try d/dx (1 + 9/16 x^4)^(3/2)

we get 3/2*9/4*x^3*(1 + 9/16 x^4)^(1/2), or

```
   (27/8)*x^3*(1 + 9/16 x^4)^(1/2), so
```

a = 2π * 2/27 * (1 + 9/16 x^4)^(1/2)  |  0->2

= 4π/27 * (10^(3/2) - 1)

which seems to be reasonable since the answer is a little bigger than 4π.

Comment: This is what I originally got and he said it was wrong too! I did this because I was just taking the perimeter of the discs and adding them and I got 2 Pi.  So then I tried it using the surface area formula with sqrt for tangent

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: Oh, duh. Add the final surface area for the end plate at x=2, or

Comment: Ohhhh!!!!!! I wonder

Comment: Good plan. But still wrong /: for both your answer + pi*r^2 on the ends and my answer plus pi*r^2 on ends. I think the prof is just wrong

Comment: I knew my answer was wrong when the end plate area was larger than the area of the revolution.